# Android Eclipse - How to get the page to scroll down with more text on it

Tags: android, android-layout, text, scroll, android-scrollview

I need some help with a contemporary art gallery app that I created from online source code and a bit of jiggery-pokery a few weeks ago. It's all working OK, but now we are adding more artists to the about artists page and there's a problem. When I add more text it just bunches up and tries to fit it all into the one screen. The relevant code is below. I thought it was something simple with the layout settings but it seems not.

If anyone could help I'd be very grateful.

Thanks,
Jonathan

If you need to download it it is available on Google Play under Flaneur Art Gallery.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >



 <Button
 android:id="@+id/buttonBack"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:text="Back"/>


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="316dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.03"
        android:gravity="top|left"

        android:text="About the artists:"
        android:textSize="15dp" />




      <TextView
        android:layout_width="316dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.03"
        android:gravity="top|left"

        android:text="RUTH SCOTT is painter who has finally been released from a desk job and can't wait to make the most of her abilities. \nARTISTX is a conceptual artist with an interest in food.\nMELANIE PHELAN creates bold and seductive pieces with a sense of strength, positivity and humour, based on the aesthetic ideal of women portrayed in mass media."
        android:textSize="12dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: add <ScrollView> where you want to make

Answer (score 0):

//try using lines or maxlines and remove the `LayoutWeight`
use `android:maxEms="30"`

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="316dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxEms="30"
        android:gravity="top|left"
        android:lines="5"

        android:text="RUTH SCOTT is painter who has finally been released from a desk job and can't wait to make the most of her abilities. \nARTISTX is a conceptual artist with an interest in food.\nMELANIE PHELAN creates bold and seductive pieces with a sense of strength, positivity and humour, based on the aesthetic ideal of women portrayed in mass media."
        android:textSize="12dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

add scrollview before your linear layout:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/edittext1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background_normal" >


      <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
 android:id="@+id/buttonBack"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:text="Back"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="316dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.03"
    android:gravity="top|left"
    android:text="About the artists:"
    android:textSize="15dp" />

  <TextView
    android:layout_width="316dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.03"
    android:gravity="top|left"

    android:text="RUTH SCOTT is painter who has finally been released from a desk job and can't wait to make the most of her abilities. \nARTISTX is a conceptual artist with an interest in food.\nMELANIE PHELAN creates bold and seductive pieces with a sense of strength, positivity and humour, based on the aesthetic ideal of women portrayed in mass media."
    android:textSize="12dp" />
   </LinearLayout>    
</ScrollView>
```

and end the scroll view tag at last

Answer (score 0):

You can place your text view inside a `ScrollView`, something like the below.  This way you'll have the button and the title label fixed on the screen and the "about" text view scrollable below it, occupying the rest of the screen.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

     <Button
     android:id="@+id/buttonBack"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="Back"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="316dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.03"
        android:gravity="top|left"

        android:text="About the artists:"
        android:textSize="15dp" />


      <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="316dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

          <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="top|left"

            android:text="RUTH SCOTT is painter who has finally been released from a desk job and can't wait to make the most of her abilities. \nARTISTX is a conceptual artist with an interest in food.\nMELANIE PHELAN creates bold and seductive pieces with a sense of strength, positivity and humour, based on the aesthetic ideal of women portrayed in mass media."
            android:textSize="12dp" />

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

You may need to adjust your weights and width/height to get the exact view you want.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who answered. This one did the trick. I'd vote if I could see what to click on !

Comment: @JonPowell To the left of the answer you can see a grey checkmark.  Click on it - and it'll become green - you've accepted the answer.